# What method can I use to name a marker in an image?

Tags: python, computer-vision, marker

I take a sequence of images, and then I identify my marker using the Hough transform from OpenCV, but now I want to name each of my markers.

What algorithm can help me? How can I use SIFT properly in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by _naming a marker_? And why do you want to use SIFT? What's your goal?

Comment: i'm doing a gait lab using vision techniques, what i refer like a marker are some ping pong balls that i attached them to the series of anthropometric body parts that i need to analyse. The flexion and deflexion of the knee change the location of my markers(ping pong balls) in y orientation. what i need is a way to naming my markers that every of my images have the same name of the marker example: marker y1 = knee, marker y2 = thigh , marker y3 = ankle,..... In the beginning i was thinking in using sift because it can identify the matching patterns but now i not sure this algorithm can help me

Comment: Basically you're trying to track a kinematic chain? If you do not put mathematic constraints on the chain (like the knee ball can move only in certain directions or you will have a broken knee hehe), you need to have something on the balls that is physically unique for each ball, for example a written number or different color. You can use any feature detector for that, although I would suggest to steer free from SIFT with has patents on it.